# Notebook for a 95 year old grandfather

Tags: laptop

My grandfather has his 95 birthday. He did use a computer in the 70s for his business but never used a PC.
We want to give him a notebook with a price point between 300€ and 400€. How do I chose the right notebook for a senior?

If it's matters I'm buying the notebook from Germany.

Comment: Chromebook, maybe?

Comment: Rather than a notebook, consider a tablet. A touchscreen is more intuitive than a mouse. And it's much harder for him to mess up his configuration compared to a Windows notebook.

Comment: I would recommend a tablet as they are much easier to use, personally I'd recommend an iPad mini

Comment: You need lower resolution and bigger screen, so that all elements on the screen will be bigger. Don't select FHD or HD+. Select HD (1366x768) and 15.6 min.